# Background image not working in rails style.css on production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets, rails-assets

Background image style works fine on local as there is no `digest` on locale, but on production, after `assets:precompile`, all assets add fingerprints and there is no non-digested asset names in Rails 4. Due to this,

```
background-image: url('abc.png')
```

does not work.

Is there any way to let background images work after `assets:precompile`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this. The file extension should be **scss**, will not work in css file.

```
background-image: url(asset_path('abc.png'));
```

Answer (score 2):

In CSS use

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'abc.png' %>)
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb

and in Sass

```
image-url("abc.png") 
image-path("abc.png")
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass

Comment: but for that i need to style.scss.erb
issue is that I have only style.scss in app/assets/stylesheets/

Comment: For the second option you don't need `.erb`

Comment: I got `SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Invalid CSS after "...und-image: url(": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "<%= asset_path 'abc"` on Rails 6

Answer (score 0):

I'd make sure that your filename has not spaces. This was the issue in my case.